# How do I expand the data set so that there is only 1 SeatNum per row using a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

[image: This is the input]

[image: This is the required output]

Here is what I have tried.The problem with the below approach is, the ROW_NUMBER() function resets the SeatNum to 1 for each distinct row.

Any help is appreciated. Another approach I tried was with the RANK and DENSE_RANK functions but they also reset the SeatNum value to 1 after the code is executed.

```
CREATE TABLE Seating (
    Section INT,
    Row INT,
    SeatNum INT,
    NumOfSeats INT,
    LastSeat INT);

INSERT INTO Seating(Section,Row,SeatNum,NumOfSeats,LastSeat)
VALUES(101,1,1,2,2),
      (101,1,3,4,6),
      (102,4,5,2,6),
      (102,5,1,2,2),
      (103,1,6,2,7);

WITH cte
AS
(  SELECT 
    Section,
    Row,
    SeatNum,
    NumOfSeats,
    LastSeat
    FROM Seating 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    Section,
    Row,
    SeatNum,
    NumOfSeats,
    LastSeat
    FROM Seating
    WHERE Section = 101 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    Section,
    Row,
    SeatNum,
    NumOfSeats,
    LastSeat
    FROM Seating
    )

SELECT 
Section,
Row,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Section,Row ORDER BY Row) AS SeatNum,
NumOfSeats,
LastSeat from cte

ORDER BY Section;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think such problems are a good opportunity to learn about [recursive CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
with cte as (
      select Section, Row, SeatNum, NumOfSeats, LastSeat, 1 as n
      from seating
      union all
      select Section, Row, SeatNum + 1, NumOfSeats, LastSeat, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < NumOfSeats
     )
select Section, Row, SeatNum, NumOfSeats, LastSeat
from cte
order by Section, Row, SeatNum, NumOfSeats, LastSeat;
```

One limitation is that the *default* number of recursion steps is 100 -- but I doubt any section has 100 seats in a row, so that is not a problem.  The default can be extended using `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a55b51a4b7b891fa694afdc87d59d02) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table value function like below and use cross apply to get desired result

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSeats
(   
    @From int,
    @To int
)
RETURNS  @GetSeats TABLE (Seat int)
AS
begin 
    declare @currnetCount int = @From;
    while(@currnetCount <= @To) begin
        insert into @GetSeats values (@currnetCount);
        SET @currnetCount = @currnetCount + 1;
    end;

    return;
END
GO
```

SELECT STATEMENT

```
SELECT        s.Section, s.Row, se.Seat SeatNum, NumOfSeats, LastSeat
FROM            Seating AS s
CROSS APPLY GetSeats(s.SeatNum, s.LastSeat) se
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Tally table and a CROSS APPLY to expand each row:

```
;WITH Tally (N) AS
(

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)

) 
SELECT Section, [Row], t2.SN SeatNumber,NumOfSeats, LastSeat 
FROM  SEATING
    CROSS APPLY  (SELECT TOP(NumOfSeats) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + (SeatNum - 1) SN FROM Tally) t2
```